# Egrep and contains in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

- `Egrep` usually expects a pattern and a file. Then Egrep searches inside
  the file for the pattern or patterns and prints the line which
  contains the specified pattern.

Now what if I want to find a pattern in a string that is inside a variable? Why do we use `<<<`? I know that < redirects what the file contains as the input of the command.

- Secondly, the `-~` symbol is used, for example, if we want to check if a character or string is inside another one. Does it always need `[[ ]]` for it to work properly?

I am new to Linux and I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `<<<` is called a "here string" and is used to pipe a *string literal or variable reference* to a command via `stdin` (as opposed to taking input from a *file*, as with `<`) - see http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html. In general, you use it whenever a tool expects stdin input rather than a command-line argument.
- I assume you mean bash's regular-expression-matching operator, `=~`; yes, it's only available inside `[[ ... ]]` conditionals.

Comment: @Lind: Glad to hear it.